# error sass/screen.scss (Line 9: File to import not found or unreadable: sass/_globals.scss

Tags: compass-sass

I have never used Compass before, although I've used Sass for a while. I'm getting the following error:

> error sass/screen.scss (Line 9: File to import not found or
>   unreadable: sass/_globals.scss.

The _footer.scss file is in the same directory as the _globals.scss file but it is saying that it is being modified when I make changes in it. What am I doing wrong?

My screen.scss file.

```
/* Welcome to Compass.
 * In this file you should write your main styles. (or centralize your imports)
 * Import this file using the following HTML or equivalent:
 * <link href="/stylesheets/screen.css" media="screen, projection" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /> */

@import "compass/reset";
@import "compass/css3";
@import "compass/layout";
@import "sass/_globals.scss";
@import "sass/_footer.scss";
```

This is my config structure:

```
require 'compass/import-once/activate'
# Require any additional compass plugins here.

# Set this to the root of your project when deployed:
http_path = "/"
css_dir = "css"
sass_dir = "sass"
images_dir = "img"
javascripts_dir = "js"

# You can select your preferred output style here (can be overridden via the command line):
# output_style = :expanded or :nested or :compact or :compressed

# To enable relative paths to assets via compass helper functions. Uncomment:
# relative_assets = true

# To disable debugging comments that display the original location of your selectors. Uncomment:
# line_comments = false


# If you prefer the indented syntax, you might want to regenerate this
# project again passing --syntax sass, or you can uncomment this:
# preferred_syntax = :sass
# and then run:
# sass-convert -R --from scss --to sass sass scss && rm -rf sass && mv scss sass
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing that you need to change:

```
@import "sass/_globals.scss";
@import "sass/_footer.scss";
```

to:

```
@import "_globals.scss";
@import "_footer.scss";
```

Your sass config file already points to the sass subdirectory, so unless your files are in a sass/sass subdirectory that's probably the problem.